# What are the possible reasons a QPluginLoader can't unload?

Tags: qt, plugins

I would like to know what are the possible reasons why a QPluginLoader can't unload (meaning the unload() function returns false).

The Qt documentation says that :

> If other instances of QPluginLoader are using the same plugin, the
>   call will fail, and unloading will only happen when every instance has
>   called unload().

I know it's not my case, therefore is there any other reasons ?

Comment: I'd suggest to try and debug into Qt itself and see where exactly it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible reason is that it is not loaded.

Check `QPluginLoader::isLoaded()` and `QPluginLoader::errorString()`.